# jQuery count tr with some condition in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 6+ table rows. Each `tr` contains 6 `td`'s.
Each `td` has a `data-name` attribute of either: `completed` or `not completed`.

I need to check which `tr`'s have 5 `td`'s with the `data-name` attribute set to `completed`.

If the row has 5 completed `td`'s set, then that `tr` should be green.

### HTML

```
<table id="workflowviz">
    <tr class="row">
        <td data-name="step1">0</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed ">1</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed ">2</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed ">3</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed ">4</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed ">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td data-name="step2">0</td>
        <td data-name="stage: completed">1</td>
        <td data-name="stage: not completed">2</td>
        <td data-name="stage: not completed">3</td>
        <td data-name="stage: not completed">4</td>
        <td data-name="Sub Stage: New ">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JS

I have written the code below for the first row based on the `data-name` attribute. But would like to avoid having to do this for each row within the jQuery loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    step1 = ($("td[title |='step1']")
                .parents()
                .children("td[title |='stage: completed']").length);

    //alert("Num of step1= "+step1);

    if(step1 == 5 ) {  

        // alert("Step 1 Done");
        $("td[title |='step1']")
            .parents()
            .addClass("done_colorgreen");
    }
    else {}
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your HTML and any JS you have written to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: add a fiddle with this scenario

Comment: Greetings from stackoverflow.! You should show some of your codes/attempts to us in order to get a good answer/solution.

Comment: see my answer for your problem..its performance is good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a jsFfiddle for you using your code..

Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("table tr").each(function() {
         if ($(this).find("td[data-name='stage: completed ']").length == 5)
             $(this).addClass("green")
     })
 });
```

and its performance is also good..

working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/172/

to see the its performance see this link and open console see time taken by this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/173/

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` to get the number of `td` elements in each row with the `completed` values. Try this:

```
$('#workflowviz tr').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    var $tds = $tr.find('td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('name') == 'stage: completed ';
    });
    if ($tds.length == 5) {
        $tr.addClass('green');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bgpj1trb/)

You would then just need to setup the `.green` class in your CSS to make the background of that particular `tr` element green.