# Edit jQuery dataTables info

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [Jquery Data table](https://datatables.net/) to present my table. I have a column which has record as Active or Inactive. Now I want to display count of number of column which has value active & inactive right after where it shows Showing 1 to 10 of 72 entries.

My table like like this
[image]

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "paging": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" ,                    //For Different Paging  Style
                "scrollY": 400,                                     // For Scrolling
                "jQueryUI": false,                                     //Enabling JQuery UI(User InterFace)
                "lengthMenu": [[30, 50, 100, -1], [30, 25, 50, "All"]],
                drawCallback: function (settings) {
                    var api = this.api(); 
                    // get the number of rows, but remove the page:current if you want number of rows in entire dataset
                    var count = api.rows({
                        api: $('#example tbody tr td[value="active"]')
                    }).data().length;
                    // this takes the count and appends it in a span tag to the dataTables pageinate div element
                    $('<span id="active_rows"></span>').html(count + ' rows').appendTo($('.dataTables_info'));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: May this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240587/jquery-count-tr-with-some-condition-in-td

Answer (score 2):

I would add an unique `#active` element to `.dataTables_info` :

```js
dom: 'lfrt<"info"i<"#active">>p',
```

Then use `drawCallback` like this

```js
drawCallback: function() {
  var active = 0;
  this.api().rows({'filter':'applied'}).every(function() {
    if (this.data().active == 'active') active++
  })
  $('#active').html(active+ ' active ...');    
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3dmpwokd/**

**Note**: If you are using a DOM-based table, evaluate with for example `this.data()[2]` instead of `this.data().active`.

I have added this CSS, I dont know how you want to present info

```css
.dataTables_info {
  float: left !important;
  clear: none !important;
}
#active {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px;
}
```

Comment: code is working but when I am fetching table data from sql then it doesn't counts rows and gives 0 rows as output. Is it because client side code executes first & then server side code gets executes?

Comment: hey @SUN, How exactly do you fetch *table data from sql*? It is not clear from the question code.

Comment: Well I have used listview control & my project made in asp.net. I am just simply binding Listview with datbase on pageload event

Comment: @SUN, like this -> shermanstechnicalblog.blogspot.dk/2015/01/… ? I really have no idea without seeing the code. Try hook into the `draw.dt` event instead of `drawCallback`, it is triggered right after -> http://jsfiddle.net/3dmpwokd/2/

Answer (score 1):

To Customize the DataTable Info ("Showing 1 to 8 of 8 entries") to as you want like ("1 - 8 of 8") Use Following event:

```
"fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
            return iStart + " - " + iEnd + " of " + iTotal;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at the events](https://datatables.net/manual/events) and use the one that gets fired after draw. Then you can call jQuery to override the text in the info element.

Specifically, the drawCallBack will get the results in the table, you can filter them as you would like then get the count.  after, just append a span or some tag to the .dataTables_paginate element.  Hope it helps a little.

```
var table = $('#notifications')
    .DataTable({
        drawCallback: function (settings) {
        //gets the table api instance    
        var api = this.api(); 

       // get the number of rows, but remove the page:current if you want number of rows in entire dataset
        var count = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data().length; 

        // this takes the count and appends it in a span tag to the dataTables pageinate div element
        $('<span></span>').html(count + ' rows').appendTo($('.dataTables_paginate'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your example which you did.

Comment: Updated answer with example

Comment: Thanks. I have applied your code but it counts no of rows. Whereas I want count rows which has active & count rows which has inactive from entire table

Comment: I have also included script I have added

Comment: Try using davidkonrad answer below his filter works for exactly what you need

Comment: davidkonard code is working but when I am fetching table data from sql then it doesn't counts rows and gives 0 rows as output. Is it because client side code executes first & then server side code gets executes?